# Auto move to next input field and return on backspace when input was max length

Tags: html, jquery

I am making an credit card input field. where I need to switch the cursor after max length of number has been input and when delete using backspace need to focus on previous field.

```js
(function ($) {
   $(".nmipay-input-field").keyup(function () {
                    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
                      var $next = $(this).next('.nmipay-input-field');
                      if ($next.length){
                          $(this).next('.nmipay-input-field').focus();
                      }else{
                          $(this).blur();
                      }
                    }
        });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#CheckoutCreditCard fieldset {
      position:relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #C5C5C5 !important;
        }

        #CheckoutCreditCard .nmipay-input-field {
         border:none!important;
      position:relative;
        }

        #CheckoutCreditCard .nmipay-input-field:focus {
          outline:none!important;
        }

        /* Change the white to any color */
         input:-webkit-autofill,
         input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
         input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
         input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset!important;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset!important;
        }

        #CheckoutCreditCard label {
          font-family: "futura-bold";
          font-size: 15px!important; 
          line-height: 2!important;
          color: #515151!important;
        }

        #CheckoutCreditCard input {
          color: #0a3956!important;
          font-family: "futura-bold";  
          min-height: 50px!important;
          font-size: 16px!important;
          background-color: transparent!important;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
              -moz-box-shadow: none!important;
        }

        input#nmipay-card-number {
            width: 54%;
        }

        input#nmipay-card-expiry {
            width: 21%;
        }

        input#nmipay-card-cvc {
            width: 18%;
      margin-right:2px;
        }
        input::placeholder {
            color: #c5c5c5;
            opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
        }

        input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
            color: #c5c5c5;
        }

        input::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
            color: #c5c5c5;
        }
        @media (max-width: 767px){
            input#nmipay-card-number {
                width: 54%;
                margin-right: 2px!important;
            }
            
            input#nmipay-card-expiry {
                width: 20%;
                padding-right: 2px!important;
            }
            
            input#nmipay-card-cvc {
                width: 15%;
            }
            
            #CheckoutCreditCard input {
                min-height: 45px!important;
                font-size: 12px!important;
            }
        }   
        
        @media (max-width: 360px){
            #CheckoutCreditCard input {
                font-size: 10px!important;
            }
      
            #add_payment_method #payment ul.payment_methods li input, 
      .woocommerce-cart #payment ul.payment_methods li input, 
      .woocommerce-checkout #payment ul.payment_methods li input {
                margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
            }

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CheckoutCreditCard" class="CC_container"">
    <div class="CC_input_group"">
      <fieldset id="nmipay-cc-form" class="wc-credit-card-form wc-payment-form">
        <input id="nmipay-card-number" class="nmipay-input-field  input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-number" type="text" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Card Number" name="nmipay-card-number" />
        <input id="nmipay-card-expiry" class="nmipay-input-field  input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-expiry" type="text" maxlength="7" autocomplete="off" placeholder="MM / YY" name="nmipay-card-expiry" />
            
        <input id="nmipay-card-cvc" class="nmipay-input-field input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-cvc" type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4" placeholder="CVC" name="nmipay-card-cvc"/>
   
        <div class="clear"></div>
       </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by checking the `length` of the value and changing focus to the `prev` field.

```
if (this.value.length == 0)
      $(this).prev('.nmipay-input-field').focus();
```

```js
(function($) {
  $(".nmipay-input-field").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      var $next = $(this).next('.nmipay-input-field');
      if ($next.length) {
        $(this).next('.nmipay-input-field').focus();
      } else {
        $(this).blur();
      }
    }
    //***** Delete Check *****//
    if (this.value.length == 0)
      $(this).prev('.nmipay-input-field').focus();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#CheckoutCreditCard fieldset {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #C5C5C5 !important;
}

#CheckoutCreditCard .nmipay-input-field {
  border: none!important;
  position: relative;
}

#CheckoutCreditCard .nmipay-input-field:focus {
  outline: none!important;
}


/* Change the white to any color */

input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset!important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset!important;
}

#CheckoutCreditCard label {
  font-family: "futura-bold";
  font-size: 15px!important;
  line-height: 2!important;
  color: #515151!important;
}

#CheckoutCreditCard input {
  color: #0a3956!important;
  font-family: "futura-bold";
  min-height: 50px!important;
  font-size: 16px!important;
  background-color: transparent!important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none!important;
}

input#nmipay-card-number {
  width: 54%;
}

input#nmipay-card-expiry {
  width: 21%;
}

input#nmipay-card-cvc {
  width: 18%;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #c5c5c5;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: #c5c5c5;
}

input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: #c5c5c5;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  input#nmipay-card-number {
    width: 54%;
    margin-right: 2px!important;
  }
  input#nmipay-card-expiry {
    width: 20%;
    padding-right: 2px!important;
  }
  input#nmipay-card-cvc {
    width: 15%;
  }
  #CheckoutCreditCard input {
    min-height: 45px!important;
    font-size: 12px!important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  #CheckoutCreditCard input {
    font-size: 10px!important;
  }
  #add_payment_method #payment ul.payment_methods li input,
  .woocommerce-cart #payment ul.payment_methods li input,
  .woocommerce-checkout #payment ul.payment_methods li input {
    margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CheckoutCreditCard" class="CC_container" ">
    <div class="CC_input_group "">
  <fieldset id="nmipay-cc-form" class="wc-credit-card-form wc-payment-form">
    <input id="nmipay-card-number" class="nmipay-input-field  input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-number" type="text" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Card Number" name="nmipay-card-number" />
    <input id="nmipay-card-expiry" class="nmipay-input-field  input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-expiry" type="text" maxlength="7" autocomplete="off" placeholder="MM / YY" name="nmipay-card-expiry" />

    <input id="nmipay-card-cvc" class="nmipay-input-field input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-cvc" type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4" placeholder="CVC" name="nmipay-card-cvc" />

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why `$(this).next('.nmipay-input-field').focus();` not working on mobile browser ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: I mean not focusing on next field

Comment: Does it not work in any mobile browsers or just one? Check the jQuery supportability of the browser.